# A bug for setcolorder function in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

The variable `b` changed when the column names of `a` changed **after** the assignment.

```
> a=data.table(x1=1:2,x2=2:3)
> a
   x1 x2
1:  1  2
2:  2  3
> b=names(a)
> b
[1] "x1" "x2"
> setcolorder(a,2:1)
> a
   x2 x1
1:  2  1
2:  3  2
> b
[1] "x2" "x1"
```

My version is 1.9.2.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known behavior and not considered a bug. You should use `copy` in this case:

```
a <- data.table(x1=1:2,x2=2:3)
b <- copy(names(a))
b
# [1] "x1" "x2"
setcolorder(a, 2:1)
b
# [1] "x1" "x2"
```

More information and a variation of this question can also be found in the "Examples" section of the documentation for `?copy`.